# Fail over solutions in a high volume application

Tags: java, architecture

I've a server which is connected to another server over a RPC connection. The number of messages that I get are over million an hour. I have to save these into DB. if there is a failure to save the messages to the DB for some reason, what should be the fail over scenario in this case? What should we make sure so that the messages will be available after the system is up?

Comment: Elaborate a bit more, is the database on the same machine, is it a disk full failure or?

Comment: Usually you would use a message broker in a cluster and it would handle failover transparently. If you want to implement something like this yourself it will be tricky...

Comment: @user3340630  Yes, the DB will be on a different machine. Say the DB has stopped responding / crashed.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I may not implement it, but, if I have to implement, what should I do?